# Existence of local time of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose we define the local time $L_0(t, \omega)$ of the standard Brownian motion $B(s, \omega): [0,t] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$
L_0(t, \omega) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2 \epsilon} m(\{ s \in [0,t], B(s, \omega) \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\}) 
$$

where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

This looks like the derivative of the push-forward measure (by the sample path $B(s;\omega): [0,t] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) with respect to the Lebesgue measure at $0$. So the existence of $L_0(t, \omega)$
just follows from apply standard real analysis results $\omega$-by-$\omega$, correct?

(I've seen arguments that use Ito's lemma to establish existence by smoothing out the absolute value function at $0$. I am wondering if this is necessary, if one is only interested in establishing existence.)

Comment: What standard real analysis result gives you the existence of the derivative at $0$?

Comment: Push-forward $\mu$ under a continuous map gives a measure that is absolutely continuous w.r.t $m$, yes? So $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{\mu(-\epsilon, \epsilon)}{m(-\epsilon, \epsilon)}$ should be the density at $0$.

Comment: In general push-forward under continuous maps does not need to be absolutely continuous. But even then the density is only defined almost everywhere, and is only equal to this limit almost everywhere, so it would not tell you that it exists at $0$.

Comment: Right. Good points. Thanks.